# Android : NDK vs CMAKE optimizations

Tags: android, performance, c++11, android-ndk, cmake

I recently switched my Android/Application mk file to a CMakeLists.txt file.

A good portion of the code is native in c/c++ (hence why cmake's debugging ability is required).

Now though, I am comparing the two builds, and the one built with ndk is much faster ...

I have added in the "-Os" flag to the

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        arguments "-Os"
    } 
}
```

block inside the build.gradle file.

My question is what is the differences of compilation here ?? What about ndk-build and cmake is different that would cause this ??

I feel as if this is a dumb question with a quick answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here :

Since we're using cmake and not ndk-build ... Build Variant actually matters for compiling native code. Building with Release fixes the performance issue.

Note : -O2 flag is included by the android.toolchain.cmake file